# How to use openXML() for Complex XMLs in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, openxml

I have the following complex XML

```
<Collection>
 <VOUCHER>
      <DATE TYPE="Date">20110401</DATE>
      <NARRATION TYPE="String">MUNNA CONVENT ROAD</NARRATION>
      <VOUCHERTYPENAME>RETAIL</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
      <VOUCHERNUMBER>R-2-I2-9-6-27751</VOUCHERNUMBER>
      <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>            
           <LEDGERNAME>U.S.T. CANTEEN</LEDGERNAME>
           <AMOUNT>-2678.9985</AMOUNT>
      </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
      <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>            
           <LEDGERNAME>U.S.T. CANTEEN</LEDGERNAME>
           <AMOUNT>-2678.9985</AMOUNT>
      </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
 </VOUCHER>
 <VOUCHER>
      <DATE TYPE="Date">20110401</DATE>
      <NARRATION TYPE="String">MUNNA CONVENT ROAD</NARRATION>
      <VOUCHERTYPENAME>RETAIL</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
      <VOUCHERNUMBER>R-2-I2-9-6-27751</VOUCHERNUMBER>
      <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>            
           <LEDGERNAME>U.S.T. CANTEEN</LEDGERNAME>
           <AMOUNT>-2678.9985</AMOUNT>
      </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
      <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>            
           <LEDGERNAME>U.S.T. CANTEEN</LEDGERNAME>
           <AMOUNT>-2678.9985</AMOUNT>
      </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
 </VOUCHER>
</Collection>
```

I'm saving voucher details in 1 table, `ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST` details in another table.

Both tables have relation on `VoucherID`. For a particular `VoucherID` the related x3 values should be stored. In my stored procedure I'm using `openxml()`.

Piece of my SP:

```
INSERT INTO SalesVoucher(AbsID,VoucherNumber,VoucherTypeName,Narration,VoucherDate)
    SELECT @AID,VOUCHERNUMBER,VOUCHERTYPENAME,NARRATION,CAST(DATE AS DATETIME)
        FROM OPENXML(@XMLHandle,'ENVELOPE/BODY/DATA/COLLECTION/VOUCHER',3) 
        WITH (    
            VOUCHERNUMBER nVarchar(200),VOUCHERTYPENAME varchar(100),NARRATION varchar(500),DATE DATETIME
            )
    SELECT @VID=@@IDENTITY

INSERT INTO SalesLedger(VoucherID,LedgerName,Amount)
    SELECT @VID,LEDGERNAME,AMOUNT
        FROM OPENXML(@XMLHandle,'ENVELOPE/BODY/DATA/COLLECTION/VOUCHER/ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST',3)
        WITH(
            LEDGERNAME varchar(200),AMOUNT decimal(18,0)
            )
```

All values are storing in DB but the column `VoucherID` in `SalesLedger` table is same for all the rows (it should not..) as I used `@@IDENTITY` it is returning last identity value only.

Please someone help me how to store related `voucherID` in `SalesLedger` table using `openxml()` in sql...

Comment: Is that correct that both `<VOUCHER>` sub-nodes are **identical** ?? What do you do if you encounter the exact same node again?? Do you insert the data twice??

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the native XQuery capabilities of SQL Server to do this. First, grab the items you need for your `SalesVoucher` table and insert those.

When you come to insert the details, your "parent" info is already stored in the `SalesVoucher` table - so go grab the necessary info from there.

Your code would be something like this (assuming your XML data is in a SQL variable called `@input` of type `XML`):

```
-- Insert the "parent" info into SalesVoucher
INSERT INTO dbo.SalesVoucher(VoucherNumber, VoucherTypeName, Narration, VoucherDate)
    SELECT
        v.value('(VOUCHERNUMBER)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(200)'),
        v.value('(VOUCHERTYPENAME)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
        v.value('(NARRATION)[1]', 'VARCHAR(500)'),
        v.value('(DATE)[1]', 'DATETIME')
    FROM 
        @input.nodes('/Collection/VOUCHER') AS Coll(V)
```

This inserts the basic info in your `SalesVoucher` table.

When you want to parse the details, you need to make a reference back to the `VoucherNumber` of the parent - with that info, you can retrieve the `AbsID` from `SalesVoucher` and insert the appropriate value into `SalesLedger`:

```
INSERT INTO @SalesLedger (VoucherID, LedgerName, Amount)
   SELECT
       sv.AbsID,
       AL.LS.value('(LEDGERNAME)[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)'),
       AL.LS.value('(AMOUNT)[1]', 'DECIMAL(18,4)')
   FROM 
       @input.nodes('/Collection/VOUCHER') AS Coll(V)
   INNER JOIN
       dbo.SalesVoucher sv 
           ON sv.VoucherNumber = v.value('(VOUCHERNUMBER)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(200)')
   CROSS APPLY
       Coll.V.nodes('.//ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST') AS AL(LS)
```

The `CROSS APPLY` gets the details for that one particular node, and thus "connects" the details to the "parent" info for the `VoucherNumber` in the XML above.

As as PS:  a datatype of `DECIMAL(18,0)` is **not** suitable for values like `-2678.9985`. `DECIMAL(18,0)` will store a maximum of 18 digits, but **0 of which** after the decimal point - so this value would be stored as `-2679`. I've changed this to a more useful datatype of `DECIMAL(18,4)` - 18 digits max, 4 of which after the decimal point.